# Difference between "program counter" and "start address"

Tags: c, gdb, embedded

I am using GDB to load an executable on an embedded device. When loading the executable, GDB says:

```
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0xf0094902 msp: 0x2001b508
Loading section .text, size 0x16240 lma 0x8000000
Loading section .data, size 0x8f0 lma 0x8016240
Start address 0x8000000, load size 92976
```

As I understand, the `pc` is the instruction pointer. I am assuming that "start address" is the starting address for the `pc`. However, in the information GDB is giving me, the start address (0x8000000, which is incidentally the same as `.text`) is *not* the same as the `pc` (0xf0094902).

What is the difference between `pc` and start address? Does is make sense to have the start address be the same as `.text`?

Comment: After loading, try `info registers` and check the value of *pc*. I suspect @dwelch is right. The registers will only have something meaninful to your application after you execute `run` on GDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "start address" referred to here is the start of the binary image, not the execution start address. The start address for execution is whatever is held in the reset vector (assuming you are using Cortex-M3 as before?).

Answer (score 5):

I assume the program counter is the current value after you loaded but *before* you started running.  When you start running, then depending on the processor of course, but it most likely describes the address to start executing that loaded code, the address to set the program counter before allowing the processor to run again.  If you run then stop quickly you should see something in the .text range for the pc 0x80000000 + 0x16240

Comment: I bet that starting PC is somewhere in the ROM bootloader.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia:" Depending on the details of the particular computer, the PC or IP holds either the memory address of the instruction being executed, or the address of the next instruction to be executed." I can't be sure, but maybe is holding the next instruction to execute.

EDIT:

You probably could find the rigth answer checking your processor documentation. For example, in MSP430 micro controller, the initial condition for the PC is the address for the reset vector. So check your processor doc to find the initial conditions of the registers.

Comment: It varies from processor to processor, in particular the programmers view of the value may have one definition where the hardware may have more than one copy one for fetching, one for the programmer to use, etc.  The programmers view of the program counter is typically documented for each processor.